# boundary problem with respect to structures

Tags: c

I want to know what is boundary problem with respect to allocation of size of structures?
Any keyword for the same that I can google shall be helpful.

Comment: It is difficult to provide an answer at this time. Can you provide more information on what it is you are actually having problems with?

Comment: @David It is an interview question and I have only this much information with respect to it.

Comment: Well, it would be better to provide the exact wording of the question rather than paraphrase it, but maybe you could look up structure alignment issues, packed vs unpacked structures, and see where that leads you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To calculate the sizes of user-defined types, the compiler takes into account any [alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) space needed for complex user-defined data structures. This is why the size of a structure in C can be greater than the sum of the sizes of its members. For example, on many systems, the following code will print **8**:

```
struct student{
  char grade; /* char is 1 byte long */
  int age; /* int is 4 bytes long */
};

printf("%zu", sizeof (struct student));
```

The reason for this is that most compilers, by default, align complex data-structures to a [word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28data_type%29) alignment boundary. In addition, the individual members are also aligned to their respective alignment boundaries. By this logic, the structure student gets aligned on a word boundary and the variable age within the structure is aligned with the next word address. This is accomplished by way of the compiler inserting "padding" space between two members or to the end of the structure to satisfy alignment requirements. This padding is inserted to align age with a word boundary. (Most [processors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_processing_unit) can fetch an [aligned word](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) faster than they can fetch a word value that straddles multiple words in memory, and some don't support the operation at all)

Referenced article: [data structure alignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment) and [Structure padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof#Structure_padding)